# Speed up a mysql query with a left join on a subquery and MAX value

Tags: mysql, subquery

This is the situation: 2 tables, one contains a list of items, the other a list of bids made on those items. Now I need to know the details of the items with the actual price. In other words, if bids have been made, I need to know the highest value out of the bid list for this item to get the current price. There are situations where there'll be other rules that apply to filter down the amount of items, but basically it comes down to this:

```
SELECT i . * , IFNULL( GREATEST( b.`made_bid` , `start_bid` ) , `start_bid` ) AS current_price
FROM `items` i
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT `bid_list`.`item_id` , MAX( `made_bid` ) AS made_bid
FROM `bid_list`
WHERE (

bid_status =1
)
GROUP BY `item_id`
)b ON b.item_id = i.id
```

And here is my problem: this works but it's slow and slowing down as more and more items are entered into the database and more and more bids are made and so the bid_list grows.

Is there a better way to write this query or would the best course here be to enter the highest current bid into an extra column of the items table and update it each time a bid is made? Somehow though, that feels wrong as I'd be stocking the same information twice.

Any help with this would greatly be appreciated.

PS, the result of the EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     i   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    839     
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    507     
2   DERIVED     bid_list    index   status  item_id     4   NULL    5726    Using where
```

PPS, indexes of the bid_list:

```
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  5367    A       
item_id BTREE   No  No  item_id 1073    A       
user_id BTREE   No  No  user_id 894 A       
status  BTREE   No  No  bid_status  1   A   YES 
made_bid_per_item   BTREE   No  No  status  5   A   YES 
                                            item_id 1073    A   
                                            amount  5367    A
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes? Can you post the output of EXPLAIN?

Comment: Can you post it in such a way that it's readable? Try editing your question.

Comment: just did, because the comment makes it a bit of a mess indeed. ;)

Comment: also post the show create table

Comment: The actual tables are a bit complex, I fear that a show create table would muddy things up

Comment: We need to at least know which indexes you have.

Comment: I'm currently testing the one you suggested, I didn't have any combined indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this subquery to go fast:

```
SELECT item_id, MAX(made_bid) AS made_bid
FROM bid_list
WHERE bid_status = 1
GROUP BY item_id
```

You should add an index on `(bid_status, item_id, made_bid)`.

Comment: Ok, this speeds things up considerably. The query of the subquery by itself now goes very fast, the query as in my question now takes 0.0061 sec instead of 0.0138 sec

Comment: That's pretty fast! In fact it was already very fast before... why did you need it to be faster?

Comment: Hey Mark, because there are only about 800 items and 6000 bids in the database and I noticed a gradual slowing down as more records are added, so I wanted to optimize the query now. Plus, as I hinted already, this is actual part of a much larger query, and I'm trying to optimize each subquery and decide if it is feasible to stack more subqueries on the main query because yet more information is requested.